# Setting image src in JQuery Mobile not working

Tags: javascript, cordova, jquery-mobile, android-virtual-device

I'm Using Visual Studio + Cordova + AVD + jQueryMobile.

Using the cordova-plugin-camera and cordova-plugin-file I get a picture. It returns a path like:

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.cordova.myapp66b652/cache/1491727086753.jpg
```

I am also able to get a more relative path using the `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` function:

```
/1491727086753.jpg
```

Whenever I attempt to set the `src` of an existing image tag:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('source-preview');
elem.src = fullCameraPath; // file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.cordova.myapp66b652/cache/1491727086753.jpg
// or 
elem.src = fileEntry.fullPath; ///1491727086753.jpg
// or
$('#source-preview').attr('src', ...);
```

```html
<img id="source-preview" style="width: 100%;" />
```

None of the above methods fail, but the HTML element is not modified and the image doesn't show. Calling the .src again does indeed show the path that was pushsed there. Only the `.attr('src', ...)` is kind enough to say:
`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` which suggests there is a problem.

However, if I manually edit the HTML in the debugger to:

```
<img id="source-preview" style="width: 100%;" src="file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/io.cordova.myapp66b652/cache/1491727086753.jpg" />
```

the image displays correctly. However, using the shorter path provided by the cordova-plugin-file does not work:

```
<img id="source-preview" style="width: 100%;" src="file:///1491727086753.jpg" />
```

This seems to tell me that the image exists, but jQuery Mobile is for some reason refusing (as some sort of "safety check") to load it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: After further, mind numbing, testing it appears that no JS edits are rendering on the image tag. If I do a `.append(<img ...>)` with the exact same code a working image also appears. It seems there is some bug with jQueryMobile refreshing, but none of the articles I've found about this have helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turns out the problem was markup. I had the callback function tied to a `<button>` within a `<form>` tag. Apparently, the default behavior of jQuery Mobile is to do a refresh of the page. I did not notice this until I changed a tag before pushing the button and saw it change back. So, because the button is in the form and doesn't point to another page, it's just a circular loop that makes the button appear like it does nothing.

Moving the button outside of the form allowed everything to start working as expected.